# Query with multiple SELECT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I will count of total area's record where there status will different like 'PENDING','SENT INFO','PTP' with group by and multiple select queries but result not got so plese help me.

My query is:

```
SELECT AREA, 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM prospectmaster WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' && STATUS = 'PENDING' GROUP BY AREA) AS PENDING, 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM prospectmaster WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' && STATUS = 'SENT INFO.' GROUP BY AREA) AS CNT 
FROM prospectmaster 
WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' GROUP BY AREA
```

I want to this type of result.

```
AREA       PENDING    INFO SENT     PTP 
AHMEDABAD   1          2             1    
GANDHINAGAR 1          5             4
KHEDA       3         10             9
```

I think some problem in query but I doesn't got it.So,Please help me.

Comment: I believe it should be `'SENT INFO'` not `'SENT INFO.'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT AREA, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PENDING, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'SENT INFO.' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PTP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PTP
  FROM prospectmaster 
 WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' 
 GROUP BY AREA;
```

If `STATUS` has 'SENT INFO.' record in DB with `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT AREA, 
         SUM(if(STATUS='PENDING',1,0)) AS PENDING, 
         SUM(if(STATUS='SENT INFO',1,0)) AS "INFO SENT",
         SUM(if(STATUS='PTP',1,0)) AS PTP 
    FROM prospectmaster 
   WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' 
GROUP BY AREA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is mysql, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT
  AREA, 
  SUM(STATUS = 'PENDING') AS PENDING, 
  SUM(STATUS = 'SENT INFO.') AS SENT_INFO,
  SUM(STATUS = 'PTP') AS PTP
FROM prospectmaster 
WHERE ZONE = 'AHMEDABAD' 
GROUP BY AREA
```

This works because in mysql true is 1 and false is 0, so summing a condition counts how many times its true